# mongodb queries find total number of cities in the database

Tags: mongodb

Hi everyone I have a huge data that contains some information like this below:

```
  { "_id" : "01011", "city" : "CHESTER", "loc" : [ -72.988761, 42.279421 ], "pop" : 1688, "state" : "MA" }
  { "_id" : "01012", "city" : "CHESTERFIELD", "loc" : [ -72.833309, 42.38167 ], "pop" : 177, "state" : "MA" }
  { "_id" : "01013", "city" : "CHICOPEE", "loc" : [ -72.607962, 42.162046 ], "pop" : 23396, "state" : "MA" }
  { "_id" : "01020", "city" : "CHICOPEE", "loc" : [ -72.576142, 42.176443 ], "pop" : 31495, "state" : "MA" }
```

I want to be able to find the number of the cities in this database using Mongodb command. But also the database may have more than one recored that has the same city. As the example above.

I tried:

```
  >db.zipcodes.distinct("city").count();
2015-04-25T15:57:45.446-0400 E QUERY    warning: log line attempted (159k) over max size (10k), printing beginning and end ... TypeError: Object AGAWAM,BELCHERTOWN ***data*** has no method 'count'
```

but I didn't work with me.Also I did something like this:

```
   >db.zipcodes.find({city:.*}).count();

  2015-04-25T16:00:01.043-0400 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

But it didn't work also and even if does work it will count the redundant data (city). Any idea?

Comment: what `didn't work mean`. The query failed, the numbers you got was wrong. If it was wrong, why was it wrong.

Comment: the first one I got : 2015-04-25T15:57:45.446-0400 E QUERY    warning: log line attempted (159k) over max size (10k), printing beginning and end ... TypeError: **********punch of cities ******** has no method 'count'

Comment: The secondone I got : 2015-04-25T16:00:01.043-0400 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregating a collection in mongo to determine counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834169/aggregating-a-collection-in-mongo-to-determine-counts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
db.zipcodes.distinct("city").count();
```

do this:

```
db.zipcodes.distinct("city").length;
```

and there is [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)  function, which may help you.

I have also found 1 [example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) on aggregate (related to your query).

If you want to add condition, then you could refer [$gte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) / [$gte (aggregation)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and/or [$lte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) / [$lte (aggregation)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/)

See, if that helps.

Comment: ok another thing  I want to do: list the cities in the state of Massachusetts with populations between 1000 and 2000.

Comment: @SalehMakkawy I have updated my answer, regarding to your above query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** for this. The aggregation pipeline has two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator stages; the first groups the documents by city and the last calculates the total distinct documents from the previous stream:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$city"            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: this also works fine thank you.  how can I change the label to be like number of city: 1645 << as example

Comment: @SalehMakkawy Do you mean changing the field `"count"` to say `"city"`?

Comment: Yes , and I did figure it out. Thank you. I'm a new in mongodb.